# Dash Plotly Textbox callback interaction

Tags: python, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have been assign to do a textbox interaction with filled area on maps. This is how my dashboard currently looks like:
[image]

So once I input my number in the text box and press submit, the figure map(which is on the left side) should show the filled area according to the number I type in in the Lat1,Long1 and Lat2,Long2. However, I am not too sure how to callback between the number input, the figure as well as the button. I went online to search but I couldnt find any resources to read from. I am very very new to this so really any help will be greatly appreciated! So if you got any ideas please please please let me know! Thank you :)

heres my code for the input box :

```
def custom_input1(paragraph_text, min_value=0, max_value=200, step=1):
    return html.Div(
        children=[
            html.P(paragraph_text, style={"paddingRight": 10}),
            dbc.Input(type="float", min=min_value, max=max_value, step=step,id='input1'),
        ],
        style={"display": "flex"},
    )

def custom_input2(paragraph_text, min_value=0, max_value=200, step=1):
    return html.Div(
        children=[
            html.P(paragraph_text, style={"paddingRight": 10}),
            dbc.Input(type="float", min=min_value, max=max_value, step=step,id='input2'),
        ],
        style={"display": "flex"},
    )
def custom_input3(paragraph_text, min_value=0, max_value=200, step=1):
    return html.Div(
        children=[
            html.P(paragraph_text, style={"paddingRight": 10}),
            dbc.Input(type="float", min=min_value, max=max_value, step=step,id='input3'),
        ],
        style={"display": "flex"},
    )
def custom_input4(paragraph_text, min_value=0, max_value=200, step=1):
    return html.Div(
        children=[
            html.P(paragraph_text, style={"paddingRight": 10}),
            dbc.Input(type="float", min=min_value, max=max_value, step=step,id='input4'),
        ],
        style={"display": "flex"},
    )
html.Div(children=[html.Div([
          html.H1("Query1", style={'text-align': 'center','fontSize': 30}),
            dbc.Row(
                [
                    dbc.Col(dcc.Graph(id="graphQ", figure={}), md=8),
                    dbc.Col(
                        children=[
                            dbc.Row(
                                [
                                    dbc.Col(custom_input1("Lat1")),
                                    dbc.Col(custom_input2("Long1")),
                                ],
                                style={"paddingBottom": 30},
                            ),
                            dbc.Row(
                                [
                                    dbc.Col(custom_input3("Lat2")),
                                    dbc.Col(custom_input4("Lat2")),
                                ],
                                style={"paddingBottom": 30},
                            ),
                            html.Div(id="output"),
                            html.Button('Submit', id='submit_button', n_clicks=0),
                        ],
                        md=4,
                    ),
                ]
            ),

        ])]))

@app.callback(
    Output("output", "children"),
    Input("input1", "value"),
    Input("input2", "value"),
    Input("input3", "value"),
    Input("input4", "value"),
)
def update_output(input1,input2,input3,input4):
    return 'Lat1: {} and Long1: {}\nLat2: {} and Long2: {}'.format(input1, input2, input3, input4)
```

heres my failed code for my figure: (not too sure if this is the right way haha…)

```
figt = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
    fill = "toself",
    lon = [{}.format(input2,input4)], lat = [{}.format(input1,input3)],
    marker = { 'size': 10, 'color': "orange" }))

figt.update_layout(
    mapbox = {
        'style': "stamen-terrain",
        'center': {'lon': -73, 'lat': 46 },
        'zoom': 5},
    showlegend = False)
```

This is the end result it should have:
[image]

Comment: What is the result that you are getting by running your code?

Comment: for the input box coding, it just displaying the textbox, button, and the figure. Dont really have any result. for the figure coding, there is an error `lon = [{}.format(input2,input4)], lat = [{}.format(input1,input3)],
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'format'` I am sure {}.format(x,x) isnt the right way but i dont know what are the code to do such function

Comment: One way you could try to avoid that issue is to try and define lon and lat as an empty list outside of the fig, append to that list using the input, and then use the original list name and set it equal to lon and lat.

Comment: Hmmm do u mind showing me the code to do that?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you only need to define one `custom_input` function here. You can call this function multiple times with different parameters. Makes the code cleaner. You probably want to make the `id` a parameter as well if you decide to do this.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden could u give me more explanation? custom_input for the button or?

Comment: I meant that you could have one function and reuse that function multiple times, see [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/WDRTBNDf) for example code that shows the idea.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden do u mind explaining what the `id="input4"` is for?  its at line 6, because I could not call out my textbox value after adding the `id="input4"`

Comment: That was my mistake, I've adjusted it.

Answer (score 0):

The formatting was a bit weird in a comment, so here's the code:

First off, at the very top you will need to define an empty list named latitude and longitude

```
longitude = []
latitude = []
```

From there, using the callback that you provided, you can update this list using

```
    @app.callback(
    Output("output", "children"),
    Input("input1", "value"),
    Input("input2", "value"),
    Input("input3", "value"),
    Input("input4", "value"),
)
def update_output(input1,input2,input3,input4):
        latitude.extend([input1,input3])
        longitude.extend([input2,input4])
        return 'Lat1: {} and Long1: {}\nLat2: {} and Long2 {}'.format(input1, input2, input3, input4)
```

And then use these values like :

```
figt = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
    fill = "toself",
    lon = longitude, 
    lat = latitude,
    marker = { 'size': 10, 'color': "orange" }))

figt.update_layout(
    mapbox = {
        'style': "stamen-terrain",
        'center': {'lon': -73, 'lat': 46 },
        'zoom': 5},
    showlegend = False)
```

And to fill in between the points/traces you can use this [link](https://plotly.com/python/filled-area-plots/#interior-filling-for-area-chart)

Comment: thank you for the code! wanted to ask what is the `#placeholder for the inputs
l1 = 20
l2 = 30
l3 = 40
l4 = 50`

Comment: Since I didn't have the inputs which are what you are trying to use, I just created placeholder values, which you can just ignore, and use your inputs instead

Comment: oh, my input values are the ones in the text box, meaning if I was to type an example "103.23" in Lat1 textbox, then l1 will be = to "103.23". so like whatever number I type in Lat1 textbox will be the number = I1. So the issue is that I don't know how to link the Input number to the longitude and latitude of the figt.

Comment: I updated the code so that it hopefully makes more sense

Comment: I tried that too but it gives me this error `Unresolved reference 'input1' `

Comment: I understood what I interpreted incorrectly, I will update the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229698/discussion-between-as11-and-rongz).